# In twilio-video, how can I subscribe to remote tracks at later time if I connected to a room with automaticSubscription set to false?

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-video, twilio-javascript

Based on example provided in [docs for twilio-video v2.x](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/migrating-1x-2x#connect-without-subscribing-to-tracks) I can connect to a chat room without automatically subscribing to any tracks published by remote participants like this:

```
  const { connect } = require('twilio-video');
  const room = await connect(token, {
    automaticSubscription: false
  });
```

If I do this then how can I subscribe to remote tracks at later time?

Comment: It has been a while and I am currently trying to solve this same problem.  Did you have any luck since you asked this question? If so, please provide the answer!

Comment: Unfortunately no. I contacted twillio devs support and they told me this feature is not available in the current version (2.0.1 at that time) and it might be something they will add later. I haven't checked since then so you can maybe research and see if this has been added.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [Twilio Track Subscription API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/track-subscriptions#mts-sdk).

or check below code for Updating Track subscription later.

```
// Find your credentials at twilio.com/console
const API_KEY_SID = 'SKXXXX';
const API_KEY_SECRET = 'your_api_key_secret';
const ACCOUNT_SID = 'ACXXXX';

const Twilio = require('twilio');

const client = new Twilio(API_KEY_SID, API_KEY_SECRET, {accountSid: ACCOUNT_SID});

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//1. At connect time Adam wants to receive all the tracks.
//   Done by default rule. No further actions required.


//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//2. After a while, Adam notices his bandwidth consumption is too high and
//   decides to unsubscribe from all video tracks

client.video.rooms('RMXXXX').participants.get('Adam')
.subscribeRules.update({
  rules: [
    {"type": "include", "kind": "audio"}
  ]
})
.then(result => {
  console.log('Subscribe Rules updated successfully')
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log('Error updating rules ' + error)
});

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//3. Later, a video screenshare track with SID MTXXXX is published to the room
//   and Adam subscribes to it.

client.video.rooms('RMXXXX').participants.get('Adam')
.subscribeRules.update({
  rules: [
    {"type": "include", "kind": "audio"},
    {"type": "include", "track": "MTXXXX"}
  ]
})
.then(result => {
  console.log('Subscribe Rules updated successfully')
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log('Error updating rules ' + error)
});

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//4. John, another participant, is in a noisy place and his audio track is
//   annoying. Adam decides to unsubscribe from it.

client.video.rooms('RMXXXX').participants.get('Adam')
.subscribeRules.update({
  rules: [
    {"type": "include", "kind": "audio"},
    {"type": "include", "track": "MTXXXX"},
    {"type": "exclude", "publisher": "John", "kind": "audio"}
  ]
})
.then(result => {
  console.log('Subscribe Rules updated successfully')
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log('Error updating rules ' + error)
});
```